# Linq search database considering duplicates

Tags: database, linq, any

I've got the problem with searching database through duplicate list values.

First I search all occurrences by given string.

```
var parentIdList =  await _context.ECATEGORIES
            .Where(a => a.NAME.ToLower().Contains(partOfName.ToLower()))
            .ToListAsync(ct);
```

then

I retrieve all names when given PARENTID of parentIdList equals database ID

```
 var mainName = await _context.ECATEGORIES
                .Where(a=> parentIdList.Any(p=>p.PARENTID==a.ID) )
                .Select(s => s.NAME)
                .ToListAsync(ct);
```

My problem is that, sometimes property PARENTID is duplicated.

For example PARENTID = {1,1,2,2,4,5,6}

then result is mainName = {"a","b","c","d","e"}

But I want mainName = {"a", "a","b","b","c","d","e"}

Comment: Do you want to de-duplicate the ParentIds? I don't understand your train of thought and duplicate ids never seem to be a good idea.

Comment: This is not my DB but by coworker and ParentId can be duplicated knowingly.

Comment: So you purposefully want duplicated ids as a result, yes?

Comment: My DB have unique PK ID, and parentid's which reference to PK ID. 
ParentId's can be duplicated and be null.
Don't ask my why is that because it's not the case of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a sequence of `Categories`, where every `Category` has an `Id`, a `ParentId` and a `Name`. You also have a string `partOfName`

You want the `Names` of `Categories`. All `Categories`? No. only those `Categories` that have a Parent which has a Name that looks like `partOfName` (*looks like* is represented by the use of the function *contains* in your code)

I'm not sure if you use entity framework. Your use of `_context` seems a hint to this. In that case, It would be easier to use the virtual parent properties. See later.

If you do not use entity framework, I'd advise to fetch your data in one query: join the elements with their parents, and keep only the join results where the parent meets your `contains` predicate:

```
string lowerCasePartOfName = partOfName.ToLower(); // for efficiency: do this only once
IQueryable<Category> categories = myDbContext.Categories;
IQueryable<Category> validParents = myDbContext.Categories
   .Where(category => category.Name.ToLower().Contains(lowerCasePartOfName))
```

Now join every Category with the validParentIds on Category.ParentId = Parent.Id

```
var query = Categories.Join(validParents, // join categories with validParents
    category => category.ParentId,         // from each category take the ParentId
    parent => parent.Id,                   // from each valid parent take the Id
    (category, parent) => new              // when they match make one new object
    {
        CategoryName = category.Name,
    });
```

Note, until now the query has been made, it has not been executed yet. If you want you can concatenate them into one big LINQ query. I'm not sure if that would increase performance very much; however, it would decrease readability.

```
var result = query.ToListAsync();
```

### Entity Framework Solution

If you use entity framework, your Category class would be like:

```
class Category
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}

     // every Category has zero or one Parent category:
     public int? ParentId {get; set;}
     public Category Parent {get; set;}

     // every Category has zero or more Children, each of them has this Category as Parent
     public virtual ICollection<Category> Children {get; set;}
}
```

You query will be much simpler:

> Give me all names of Categories whose Parents have a name that looks like partOfName

```
string lowerCasePartOfName = partOfName.ToLower();
var result = myDbContext.Categories
    // keep only the Categories whose name looks like:
    .Where(category => category.Parent.Name.ToLower().Contains(lowerCasePartOfName))
    .Select(category => category.Name);
```

Comment: I use EF, but why you used Parent as a type which it is not a type.

Name and ParentId are in the same table.

Comment: Take a second look: `Parent` is the identifier of the Property. The type of the property is `Category`. In my entity framework example `ParentId` and `Name` are also in the same table. Next time, if you use entity framework, give us your classes. This helps us giving you an answer

Comment: Ok I see but still is not the case. You wrote "Give me all names of Categories whose Parents have a name that looks like partOfName".  I want "Give me all categories that looks like partOfName and then add to every found category info about their parent name or set null if don't have parent" But thanks for your post tomorrow I try to that better.